# drawImage not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I have a Sprite prototype that has a constructor function...

```
function Sprite(img) {
    for (var property in img) this[property] = image[property];
}
```

...that takes in an Image object and makes a copy of it. Now I'm trying to draw the Sprite using drawImage:

```
Sprite.prototype.draw = function(ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.drawImage(this, x, y);
}
```

this gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

however if I use the actual Image object and otherwise the same exact code i.e.:

```
Sprite.prototype.draw = function(ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}
```

it works exactly as it should(img is the global name for the Image object).

This is the entire code for the Sprite prototype. I don't understand what difference is causing this to happen as I've only added the one function to Sprite; draw.

Comment: [drawImage only supports native objects.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934033/draw-preloaded-image-into-canvas).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean:

```
 this[property] = img[property]
```

Other than that I think your copy is shallower than you need.  Check out this discussion to put the prototype methods into your copy.  [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Finally I would caution, unless you are altering the images somehow, it's more efficient to reuse the same image. Have canvas objects reference the same image.